# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php, pdo

I have this PHP function which has been working very well until i reinstalled my dev system:

```
function connectDB($database, $username, $password) {

    $DSN = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database";

    try {
        $DBH = new PDO($DSN, $username, $password); <--- LINE 10
        return $DBH;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Could not connect to the database.\n");
    }
}
```

And i'm getting the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /var/www/im/tools.php on line 10
```

I checked phpinfo() and PDO is enabled:

PDO drivers : mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL version: 5.1.54

The interesting thing is that the interaction with th MYSQL database is ok, but i'm still getting the error when debugging.

I'm puzzled about this error! My system is Ubuntu 11.04 + NGINX + PHP 5.3

Any tip to get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: "the interaction with th MYSQL database is ok, but i'm still getting the error when debugging." What does that mean?

Comment: The function is working ok, i can query the DB, but in the Eclipse debug interface i get that "fatal error".

Comment: Check `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/*` and make sure `pdo.so` is enabled there too. (It seems like only the CGI/mod_php version has it enabled.)

Comment: extension=pdo.so is just in pdo.ini . There are several .ini in the directory you mentioned, but i'm not sure adding extension=pdo.so to every file is the solution. I tried adding to mysql.ini but with no result.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using namespaced code? Maybe you need to use \PDO class then?

Comment: The code where the class is invoked is in the question. I don't think it's namespaced.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if there is a php.ini file in the web app's current working directory. If one has been placed there to change certain settings, it will override the global one.

To avoid this problem, don't use a php.ini change settings; instead, do this in the vhost declaration or a .htaccess file with 'php_flag'.

See also [PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found/)

Comment: Why downvoted? I strongly suspect that you answer might be right. I'm having the same issue, but only for cronjob-runned scripts and the problem started exactly after a new php.ini file was installed in my root folder. But since your answer was downvoted, I was wondering if you have more info on this, I don't want to mess the server configuration!

Comment: PS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561937/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found-only-on-cron-job/16562026?noredirect=1#16562026

Comment: I have no idea why I was downvoted on this.  I suspect it was by people who think they are experts, and therefore think any given problem could only have one cause.

Comment: Are you running the cronjob as root?  If so, maybe the php.ini is only readable by root and therefore is being ignored by Apache.

Comment: Probably you're right, no idea, but anyway the problem was the one you pointed out. Removing the php.ini in the root folder got things going again as before. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 yum install php-pdo

 service httpd restart
```

Comment: yum? Shouldn't it be apt?