# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, web-applications

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /home/bd/public_html/app/webroot/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php on line 177
```

PHP INFO:

```
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, sqlite2, mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => 5.5.24

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.7.7.1
```

PHP INI:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

CODE:

```
/**
 * Check whether the MySQL extension is installed/loaded
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
        public function enabled() {
                return in_array('mysql', PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
        }
```

Ideas as to why I'm getting this error?

PHP 5.3.15
CloudLinux/CentOS 6
CPanel

Comment: What's the output of `debug(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`

Comment: Seems like a service-level support question?

Comment: "Debug setting does not allow access to this url" added that to it's own php file and ran it.

Comment: how did you obtain the php_info output? if you did it from the CLI the output may be different as cPanel uses a separate PHP binary to the CentOS one.

Comment: phpinfo(); and cli all use the same binary

Comment: has your setup worked before? did you make changes? can you provide some details on what you did to end up with this? and if not too much maybe show the output of `phpinfo();` from CLI and from browser.

Comment: Never worked with a script that needed PDO before. Was installing it and noticed it used PDO it looks like.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve this? it may help me too

Answer (score 78):

try

```
 yum install php-pdo
 yum install php-pdo_mysql

 service httpd restart
```

Comment: @s4suryapal: run it in console command line of server linux. On window, you can uncommend line with: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll in php.ini (ex: xampp, wamp, ...) and restart apache

Comment: the question meant he has pdo installed (quote from phpinfo), so -1.

Comment: How do i install php pdo for oracle on cent os 5.8 ?

Answer (score 75):

Try adding `use PDO;` after your namespace or just before your class or at the top of your `PHP` file.

Comment: That did it for me... I was inside a namespaced class, and simply adding a ` \ ` in front of `PDO` as suggested elsewhere didn't work - but this did :)

Comment: Question didn't mention he was using namespace. if some one use namespace for all other customer classes this should be the acceptable answer. Because somewhare in the code he missed `use PDO` Otherwise need to install correct PDO version libraries into their webserver.

Comment: This helped me out a bunch. Thank you. This works too if anybody wonders because PDO is a global class within PHP.

Answer (score 22):

This can also happen if there is a `php.ini` file in the web app's current working directory.  If one has been placed there to change certain settings, it will override the global one.

To avoid this problem, don't use a `php.ini` file to change settings; instead you can:

- Specify settings in the vhost declaration
- Use an `.htaccess` file with `php_flag` ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php))
- Use an `.user.ini` file ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php))

Comment: Hi Alastair, I expanded your answer slightly. Hope that's OK. ;-)

Comment: Can you give an example of how to add pdo in .htaccess please? Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Ensure they are being called in the php.ini file

If the PDO is displayed in the list of currently installed php modules, you will want to check the php.ini file in the relevant folder to ensure they are being called. Somewhere in the php.ini file you should see the following:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

If they are not present, simply add the lines above to the bottom of the php.ini file and save it.

Answer (score 10):

What is the full source of the file `Mysql.php`. Based on the output of the php info list, it sounds like you may be trying to reference a global class from within a namespace.

If the file `Mysql.php` has a statement "namespace " in it, use `\PDO` in place of `PDO` - this will tell PHP to look for a global class, rather than looking in the local namespace.

Comment: well no namespaces there, I'm stumped again.

Comment: I'm just wondering if maybe this is a poorly coded script. I had to actually move the Cake framework into the webroot directory just to even get this far ;/ script is: http://www.freereviewscript.com/p/requirements

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on **GoDaddy**. I added the `extension=pdo.so` to `php.ini`, still didn't work. And then only one thing came to my mind: **Permissions**

> Before uploading the file, kill all PHP processes(cPanel->PHP Processes).

The problem was that with the **file permissions**, it was set to `0644` and was not executable . You need to set the file permission at least `0755`.

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 3):

you can just find-out loaded config file by executing below command,

```
 php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

Then add below lines to correct php.ini file

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

Then restart web server,

```
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Its a Little Late but I found the same problem and i fixed it by a "\" in front of PDO

```
public function enabled() {
    return in_array('mysql', \PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
}
```

Comment: you can use multi_query for what you described (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22469722/2943403), but you shouldn't.  `multi_query()` does not allow parameterization.  Use a single prepared statement with looped executions and grab the new ids as you go.

Comment: Adapt this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25939954/2943403 to get the new ids  let me know when you've read these comments so that I can delete them.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by `PDO` not being available to PHP.

If you are getting the error on the command line, or not via the same interface your website uses for PHP, you are potentially invoking a different version of PHP, or utlising a different `php.ini` configuration file when checking `phpinfo()`.

Ensure PDO is loaded, and the PDO drivers for your database are also loaded.

Comment: It is loaded as mentioned in comments above.

Comment: +10 That's so ridiculous to vote down...it's exactly what happens with me..after upgrading PHP to 7.1 PDO not available...some downvoters really weird. is this kind of a hobby in the stack?

Comment: I think a lot of people don't realize this site is a resource for everyone, not just OP.   Not every answer will be _specifically_ of use to OP, but that doesn't mean they will be of no use to others.  This one was the clue I needed, for instance.  Upvoted.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For Fedora 33 you can install as follows:

Install

```
dnf install php-pdo
dnf install php-pdo_mysql
```

Restart PHP

```
systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

Comment: It works!! After adding Remi repo of course. Great! Thank You! :) After several years with Ubuntu and apt it is hard to use Yum.

Comment: Note: It is necessary to run commands with `sudo`

Comment: yes you need sudo, I run them under the root user.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with library [PHP_PDO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phppdo/) , because my hosting provider didn't accept my requirement for installation of PDO driver to apache server.

Comment: Hi, can you guide me how to add library to cpanel because I am on shared hosting and stuck in this.

Comment: Thanks bro you are awesome. Working PDO... :)

Comment: Hi, can you guide me how to add library to cpanel because I am on shared hosting !

Comment: Ramesh Kumar : just include  PHP_PDO to beginning your exists code

Answer (score -1):

If you run php with php-fpm module,do not forget to run command systemctl restart php-fpm!That will reload php-fpm module.

Comment: It is looking like a comment and does not provide the answer at all to the answer at all.

Answer (score -1):

I had to run the following on AWS EC2 Linux instance (PHP Version 7.3):

```
sudo yum install php73-php-pdo php73-php-mysqlnd
```

Answer (score -1):

If anyone getting this error in cPanel, please check the PHP version type in your cPanel. Change it, `alt-php` to `ea-php`. This setting worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

After a long time, I finally solved it. check your folder in Cpanel to see if there is a php.ini file. if yes delete it since Cpanel will be using its own php.ini