# Class PDO not found

Tags: php, class, pdo

I've got this code set up in one of my .PHP files, and I keep running into the error:

**
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/ben/public_html/sub/classes/article.php on line 62**

My PHP code on line 62 is:

```
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
```

Comment: The php's pdo extension is not installed or not enabled in the php config. Check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found

Comment: It's hosted online on a webserver right now, how should I go around getting it set up if Im not given direct access to php.ini

Comment: Then you probably can't, ask your hosting provider to enable it, check the answers in the link I posted above, I think they discuss all possible cases.