# pdo module is enabled but I have "PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found"!

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I uploaded my laravel 5.3 on a shared hosting.
When I go to my site ,I have a blank page. in the root of

> [29-Jan-2017 10:57:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /home/rasooli/reka.ir/private/config/database.php on line 16

But the pdo and pdo_mysql extensions are selected on this hosting. What can i do with this error?
Are this extensions sufficient for laravel 5.3?
[https://m24i.imgup.net/Screenshot4e76.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MlYX.png)

Comment: I think need to update your hosting php.ini file. So you can inform you hosting management's they can solve it. You can learn https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found-in.288391/    AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found

Comment: I created a phpinfo from host settings:
http://reka.ir/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the PDO was enabled in php.ini.
but problem caused by php version and by upgrading php, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to enable pdo in you php.ini
you can create it in your root :
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so