# Class 'PDO' not found - PDO drivers installed

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

on my server, PDO drivers are installed.

```
http://randani.com/test.php
```

but on my sub-domain I got this error message:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Class 'PDO' not found
```

my sub-domain:

http://dev.randani.com/

where is my wrong?

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?q=Class+%27PDO%27+not+found+site:stackoverflow.com&safe=off&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw4f-K69LcAhVEyKYKHUxwArAQrQIoBDAAegQIABAN&biw=1110&bih=786

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found)

Comment: all of the answers said to install PDO. but on my server PDO drivers are installed.

Comment: is there a link to check your phpinfo ?

Comment: @shakee93 http://randani.com/test.php

Comment: did you try using PDO on a single php file ? does it work ?

Comment: Does error occur in console CLI application or is it browser HTTP request? If console, then your PHP may load different php.ini without PDO.

Comment: this url is laravel welcome page: http://dev.randani.com/