# Class 'PDO' not found after updating the php version to 7.2 via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdo

Already checked this one: [PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found) and many other answers.

I created a .htaccess file in the website root folder:

```
# PHP 7.2
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Then I started having

```
Class 'PDO' not found
```

PS: I am using shared hosting therefore upgrading to php7.2 is only possible via .htaccess. Is there a way to update .htaccess so it can use pdo?

Comment: Nope. Contact your host's support.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed by. I already checked the provided link, provided that in the first line of the question. This question is not duplicate and none of the answers in 'PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found' link resolved the issue. @Your Common Sense