# CLASS PDO not found on installing a PHP Script

Tags: php, class, pdo

[SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2rc6.png)

I've got this code set up in one of my .PHP files, and I keep running into the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PDO" not found in /home/dashiapp/public_html/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:1335

**My PHP code on line 62 is:**

```
return static::$resolvers[$driver] ?? null;
```

Comment: Do this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, are you sure this problem is really related to MySQL or MySQLi?

Comment: "I've got this code set up in one of my .PHP files" - It this really an application you're writing or it's just an expression to mean that you're trying to install some third-party application?

Comment: Alvaro Gonzalez it's a Third Party Application@ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @NicoHaase it's actually with Boompay Payment Gateway PHP Script.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC honestly, I need more elaboration. Can we have a meeting, where I can share screen?

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question**, not to the comment section. Also, share the code involved that helps others to reproduce the problem