# PDO does not get recognized on my Linux

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, debian, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use PDO on my raspbian(raspberry pi) distro, wheezy, debian. This is the error I get when executing a PDO connection to mysql dbms:

> Fatal error: Class '`PDO`' not found in `/var/www/labCrawl/Data.php` on line 7

php code that throws error:

```
$pdo = new PDO(DB_CONN_STRING, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Also, my code is working fine on my osx machine, but when I put it on my pi, pdo fails to be recognized.

I have ran the following command line and results checded out as listed below:

```
$ php -i|grep PDO
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

Now, I have checked my php.ini in /etc/php5/apache2 and the following bolded extensions concerning PDO are there:

> `extension=imap.so`
>   `extension=yaz.so`
>   `extension=mcrypt.so`
>   `extension=gettext.so`
>   `extension=pgsql.so`
>   `extension=pdo_pgsql.so`
>   **`extension=pdo.so`
>
>   `extension=pdo_mysql.so`**

Other info, on the pi, there are a whole bunch of `.ini` files that are linked through a conf.d directory in /etc/php5/apache2. Files like `20-pdo_mysql.ini`, which all have same content (pretty much nothing, I think!):

> `; configuration for php MySQL module`
>   `; priority=20`
>   `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Versions of mysql: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian, and php5 ver: 5.4.35-0+deb7u2 (cli)

Can anyone see what I could be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have mysql and mysql-server installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813381/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012881/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found)

Comment: mysql and mysql-server are installed and working fine. However, I read over a possible duplicate issue link listed above by Rikesh and Tobi...

Comment: I checked to see if some of my old mysql connections in php that do not use PDO, and they were failing as well, So, I went back to an old php.ini file, and is back online, doing some more testing with PDO, but to get right results, but I am not getting the PDO error anymore. Thanks everyone for help so far, I will update any solutions or if I have further issues in a few! Cheers!